# The act of talking to somebody about the same thing over and over

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What do I say for somebody keeps bringing up and talking into somebody's ear about the same topic again and again till he is fed up and finally agrees to it?

**Example:** Mary's been [word or idiom] to John till he finally bought it for her.

Comment: It's [**nagging**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/nag) if it's really annoying.

Comment: *Mary's been bugging John.*

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul However, the possible duplicate question **also** focuses on the ***sound*** a person makes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's  called [**nagging**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/nag) if it's really annoying.

Best use the simple past tense though if the subordinate sentence is in the past simple.

> Mary [**nagged** at](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/nag_1?q=nag) John till he finally **succumbed** and **bought** it for her.

Examples

> She's been nagging about it since this morning
>   He's always nagging at her for staying out late

Comment: I was under the impression that nagging is used for kids only. But it looks like that we can use it for kids and grown-ups alike.

Comment: @user385505 absolutely, just look at the examples cited by Lexico in the first link. Plenty of adults speaking there.

Answer (score 1):

From [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/harp-on?q=harp+on) the phrasal verb **to harp on about sth** is one possibility, but it is informal.

- Mary's been harping on about it to John till he finally bought it for her. (*informal, disapproving*)

This other one, the phrasal verb **to bang on (aboutsth)**, used in British English only, ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/bang-on?q=bang+on))
is informal too.

- Mary's been banging on about it to John till he finally bought it for her. (*informal*)

Comment: How harp on about sth is different from nagging?

Comment: @user385505 I'd say that the annoying thing about either "nagging" or "harping on" is made more explicit, more salient in "nagging".

Answer (score 0):

> **Pester (verb):** If you say that someone is pestering you, you mean that they keep asking you to do something, or keep talking to you, and you find this annoying — [Collins Dictionary](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/pester)

Example: 
John has been pestering her to go out with him all month.

Alternatively, you could say *Persecute, badger or plague*.

Comment: Does pester involves harassing sb to do sth or just repeatedly talk to sb about sth till we get what we want. Beside is it day to day talk or rather formal.

Comment: @user385505 Yes. I use it all the time in casual speech.

Answer (score 0):

Example: Mary's been **going on** or **getting on** to John till he finally bought it for her. - informal/colloquial